# What is the significance of .: in classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

The title has it all, when setting up a class path to be used by your program, what is the significance of `.:` construct?

Consider

```
/Library/Java/Home/bin/java -cp $APP_HOME/lib/*.jar::  Handler
```

vs

```
/Library/Java/Home/bin/java -cp .:$APP_HOME/lib/*.jar::  Handler
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paths in the classpath are separated from one another by `:`. So `.` is just the first entry in the classpath list, which refers to the *current directory*.

Answer (score 0):

For the code particular fragment given above:
/Library/Java/Home/bin/java -cp .:$APP_HOME/lib/*.jar:

this would mean the current directory (denoted by '.') is to be looked at first before all the jars in the $APP_HOME directory.

: is the classpath separator in unix whereas ; is the classpath separator in windows.